Create solana dvpn
I've started a new open-source DVPN project on Solana, and I invite everyone to join us: https://github.com/sanaderi/Solana-DVPN.
I need some help with the scenario:
DVPN-Client: Users can select a plan, such as Free or 1 Month, and pay for it with SOL. We then create a record in the Solana program, including the owner and expiration date. When the user tries to connect, we check this record and return a random server configuration.
DVPN-Server: When registering a device as a server, even a mobile phone, we set the server configuration on-chain. Based on the service time provided, the server earns SOL. I want the server to be able to claim their earnings at the end of each epoch.
I have some issues with this scenario and would appreciate your insights on how we can implement it. I’m looking forward to your thoughts and help!
